# Layout issue - right hand side column overlapping footer

Tags: bug

When I edit my question and scroll down, the right hand side column overlaps the footer.
I am not sure if it should be that way, but it feels a bit strange.

[image: UI screenshots]

I use Firefox 46.0.1.

Comment: Just FYI, this Is a no-fix bug

Comment: Oh, my bad. I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for your response!